# I need help regarding travel to Lisbon from Pakistan

Tags: transit, spain, pakistani-citizens, barcelona

I am traveling from Pakistan to Lisbon. I have a 30-day visa from Portugal.

I will be transiting in Barcelona. Do I need another transit visa for Spain? Can I use the transit area of the Barcelona airport?

Here is my itinerary:

1. Multan (Pakistan) - Doha (Qatar)
2. Doha - Barcelona
3. Barcelona - Lisbon

Comment: What do you want to know?

Comment: This is really hard to follow.  Could you check your spelling ? We'll try and clean it up a bit, but it's difficult to see. I presume you have a Pakistani passport?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a separate visa to transit a Schengen port if you already have a Schengen visa. You will be fine in both Barcelona and Lisbon.

Number of entries might matter in some cases but not in this one.

Answer (score 2):

You will clear Schengen passport control in Barcelona, leaving the international transit zone for the area of the airport devoted to internal Schengen flights.  Your Schengen visa issued by Portugal is valid for this purpose.

Because Portugal and Spain are both in the Schengen zone, your flight will depart from the area of the airport devoted to internal Schengen flights, just the same as if your flight were a domestic flight from Barcelona to Madrid.  There will be no passport control in Lisbon.

> Do I need another transit visa for Spain?

No.

> Can I use the transit area of the Barcelona airport?

Yes, and you can (and will) leave it, too.